# Que tipo debo usar para tener atributos que guarden una imagen y/o PDF respectivamente en JAVA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-mvc

Estoy desarrollando una web-app java spring con JPA. En los HTML tengo fomulários con inputs type="file" y type="image".

Mi problema es que no se que **tipo** poner en los atributos de las clases en JAVA para guardar estos archivos.

**Clases con sus atributos:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="noticias")
public class Noticia {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String titulo;
    private ????? foto;
    private String texto;
    private Date fecha;...}
   

@Entity
@Table(name="reclamos")
public class Reclamo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String NISoAsociado;
    private String telefono;
    private String observacion;
    private Date fecha;
    private List<?????>archivos;...}
```

La **Noticia** solo recibe una imagen mientras que el **Reclamo** puede recibir de 1 a 3 archivos(imagen o PDF).

Los tipos que no se definir estan con signos de pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack overflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y  [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: Para guardar imágenes y otros tipos de ficheros (pdf en tu caso) en base de datos, tienes dos opciones La primera es guardar los ficheros (imágenes y pdf) como ficheros normales en algún directorio del servidor. En base de datos guardarías el path de dichos ficheros. Tu *private ??? foto* sería algo como *private String foto* donde el contenido sería algo como "c:\path\foto.png". Si esta opción no te vale y quieres guardar en la base de datos el fichero (foto/png), el tipo de campo es de array de bytes byte[]. Guardarías en esos campos los bytes de la imagen tal cual o del pdf. Se bueno.

Comment: Para almacenar imágenes en Java, puedes usar el tipo de dato "BufferedImage" de la biblioteca Java AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit). Este tipo de dato representa una imagen en formato raw en memoria y proporciona métodos para manipular y procesar la imagen. Para almacenar archivos PDF en Java, puedes usar el tipo de dato "File" de la biblioteca Java IO (Input/Output). Este tipo de dato representa un archivo o un directorio en el sistema de archivos y proporciona métodos para manipular y acceder a los archivos. Por ejemplo, si quieres crear una variable que almacene una imagen, podrías usar el sig